# Google form sync with Fusion Table fails if \ (backslash) is present

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I am using this google script to transfer data from google web form to fusion table.
http://fusion-tables-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/FusionTablesFormSync/src/formsync.js

This works perfectly well, except in cases when any field of my webform includes \  character, and script results in "Exception: Invalid query: Parse error near...."

Example of Web form input field data:-

10^{23}\;atoms

Is it possible to fix (where?) in the script, which probably builds malformed query to fusion table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just committed a new version of the script that fixes the unescaped backslashes, as well as correcting the timestamp format so Fusion Tables knows what to do with it.

Comment: There seems something not quite right with this new script. The web form input goes missing and not stored in excel as well.      Please confirm if this has been tested.

Comment: Yes, I tested it multiple ways before posting the update. Are you seeing any errors in the Apps Script log?

Comment: Thanks. This is working now. I had 2 "on submit form" triggers, which for some reasons was preventing fusion table update.